# Delphi factorial operations precision

Tags: algorithm, delphi

**SITUATION**

I need to make a program for my maths course about Combinations and Permutations. If you want to calculate them you have to deal with factorials and I have written this typical recursive function:

```
//TCombinazioni is a class that I have created to solve Combinations
function TCombinazioni.fattoriale(const x: integer): Int64;
begin

 Result:= 1;
 if x > 0 then
  begin
   Result:= fattoriale(x-1)*x;
  end;

end;
```

---

**PROBLEM**

I have written this code in my class `TCombinazioni`:

```
function TCombinazioni.getSoluzioni: Int64;
begin
  //C(n,k) = (n+k-1)! / (k! * (n-1)!)
  Result := fattoriale(n+k-1) div (fattoriale(k) * fattoriale(n-1));    
end;
```

The code itself is correct and if `n` and `k` (both integers) are small the function returns the desired number. The problem comes out when you input big numbers because the factorial grows up very quickly. Here you see an example.

[image]

On the left you can see that the output 11440 is correct but on the right it is not correct. I know that this kind of computation is "dangerous" because I am dealing with big integers, even if they are declared as `Int64`.

The type `Int64` is the biggest type of integer as far as I know, but is there any other possibility if I am trying to make calculations with big integers?

**Possible soluton(s)**

1. Very easy, I could set that n and k cannot be greater than 10 for example (but I prefer not doing so)
2. Using floating point arithmetic. I was thinking that I could use the `getSoluzioni` function with an `Extended` return value (instead of Int64). Since the result of these operations **must** be an integer, I could check if the double has a decimal part equal to zero. If not, I'll not accept the result.

I was considering point number 2 because Extended has a wider range of values than Int64. Is the Extended division in Delphi more precise than Int64 division?

I would like to be able to have a decent result with at least n=14 and k=8 for example.

Comment: SOLUTION: As David suggested me I have found a BigIntegers unit online by Rudy Velthuis that is very good. That allows me to calculate C(32,28) which is very impressive! ( C(32,28) = 55317304280338408 if you can read it )

Comment: At first you would better to exploit algorithmic approach as David described.

Comment: For the record, Int64 is signed integer with a size of 64 bits. You have UInt64 which is a unsigned integer with a size of 64 bits, so you lose negative values but you can represent more positive ones

Comment: @agustin true but it does not help much with factorial where growth is, er, well, factorial

Comment: @David sure, Big Integers will suffice better in this case. Just a small point I made for clarification

Comment: Yes, BigIntegers is the best solution. There is an approximation of the factorial that involves exponential and math PI in which you can use Extended, but that's NOT the case

Comment: Since your logical range required is 0..32 (I'm assuming that 33! is not representible in Velthius' library) then I'd suggest you simply declare an array containing each value and use that array directly (or via a function if you insist). That way, you don't perpetually waste time calculating a recalculating the values using a recursive function.

Comment: No, I can calculate 60! with Velthius' library for example. That is good enough, it also has the BigDecimal unit

Comment: Tsk, tsk, tsk. It is VelthUIs, not VelthIUs. <g>

Comment: @Magoo: in my library, you can represent a lot. An integer with 10,000,000 digits is no problem.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I was about to install & play with such, so I had no idea what its max capacity was. OP talked in turms of 32! so I concluded it maxed out at 33! or so. My point is that regardless of how many times it's calculated, m! is m! so it's pointless having once calculated any particular factorial to perpetually re-calculate the same number as combinatoric exercises. Much better to save the results in an array or list where they can be retrieved quickly. In fact, perhaps a good library extension would be to set off a thread to build such a list so factorial becomes a fast simple method.

Comment: @Magoo: Calculating them each time is useless. But you still need a BigInteger library to manipulate them. FWIW: http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html

Comment: @AlbertoMiola: I acquired the title Lord Cancellor when I cancelled a lot of messages in the Borland and Embarcadero forums. <g>

Comment: Using Delphi like a boss in math and engineering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extended has 64 bits of precision so no gain there. Plus it greatly complicates the coding. You could certainly make the calculation less prone to overflow by rewriting it to do the divisions as you go along. That will help to a degree. So when you find the same factor in both numerator and denominator simply remove it from both.

But really what you need is a big integer library. Search the web to find one.

Comment: Yes I think I need something like that (int library) since Delphi is not so good with maths stuff. I also guess that so far I can't do better than what I've done

Comment: Don't think Delphi is that different from other comparable languages in this regard.

Comment: Sure you are right. My bad because I did not specify in my comment that I'm used to do this kind of stuff with python, which is better (for a maths purpose). I have found a big integer library online, I guess that it will be my savior

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's different in the sense that there still isn't a BigInt offered in the standard library, unlike many other major language platforms.